# Wordpress Plugin Pinpoint is not working as intended

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using https://pinpoint.world/wordpress/ it works as intended with the exception that it allows day gaps, for example:

If there is 1 room available and someone buy it from december 10 to december 15, and then someone wants it for december 7 to december 10 it doesnt let him. It should as check in and check out should not collide on the same day. I'm lost on this one, help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding on 
includes/search/class-frontend-search-results.php
the following code:

```
if($check_out != $check_in){
    $check_out = new DateTime($check_out);
    $check_out->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $check_out = $check_out->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

That worked for me, because the backend code works, what is wrong is the frontend datepicker.

Comment: Thanks! that was what I needed